# PHP foreach loop on an array returning multiples of the same data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a session variable array called 'section_remember' with 2 values in it.
I am expecting the code below to result in a single "print_r" and give me two div's (one for each value in the array).

Instead it executes 2 print_r's and gives me 4 div's, if that makes any sense.

If the array has 3 values in it it runs the loop 3 times and results in 3 print_r's and 9 div's. And so on depending on the number of values in the array.

I don't understand why it's doing this, but I'm new to PHP so I'm hoping it's something obvious.

```
<?php
    print_r($_SESSION['section_remember']);

        foreach($_SESSION['section_remember'] as $key =>$value)
        {       
        $sql = "SELECT `section`.`start`,`section`.`stop`,`section`.`title`,`daily_show`.`audio_file`
            FROM `section`
            INNER JOIN `daily_show`
            ON `section`.`daily_show_id` = `daily_show`.`id`
            WHERE `section`.`id` = $value";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {       
            $title = $query['title'];
            $seconds = $query['seconds'];
            $duration = gmdate ('i:s', $seconds); //'H:i:s' for hours

            echo "<div><span class='duration'>".$duration."</span>".$title."</div>";        
        }   
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: wrie your full query instead of   $sql = "SELECT blah blah blah....";

Comment: ... and the value of $_SESSION['section_remember']

Comment: Sounds like you're including / running this script multiple times somehow as the `print_r()` is outside any loops yet you're seeing it more than once. Unless of course your question isn't a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: value of $_SESSION['section_remember'] is Array ( [0] => 58 [1] => 59 )

Comment: I am running the same SQL query on the same SESSION array later on in the code on the page, but the end result of the second query is not echoing out the same stuff, and there are no print_r's in the second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that the print_r() call is outside the loop and you get it to output three times, that means it's inside a greater loop (or, say, a function being called three times). The code you've sent is not to blame here.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that it's something else on the page. The rest of the code is a convoluted and poorly organized mishmash of jquery and PHP and not really fit to post.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between print_r and foreach loop in your code.

Foreach loop will output 2 divs (as there are 2 values), and will echo it after the print_r result.

What is the purpose of that print_r? If you want the values to be inside it, you need to create another array inside the loop and only after that use print_r($arr).... It'l do the trick.

P.s. For indexes, you can assign $i = 0 outside the loop, and $i++ just before end of the loop.

I am on mobile right now. If you didn't get it, tell me and i'l insert this in your own code snippet when i can.

Answer (score 0):

you appear to be printing and echoing the same information.

maybe if you tried it by commenting out the first `print_r` statment.

```
//print_r($_SESSION['section_remember']);

        foreach($_SESSION['section_remember'] as $key =>$value)
        {       
        $sql = "SELECT `section`.`st
```